# Counting the Number of Days an Entry is Active within a particular month using a Date Range in Proc SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, cartesian-product, proc-sql

I am earning some data over a period of time but have hit a wall at figuring out some specifics.

For example I have a large number of rows of data that have an activity `START` and `STOP` date. I have performed a cartesian product to join my particular rows of data to that particular month if one of three cases occurs:

1. The Item Activity START date occurs before the first day of that particular month and that item's activity stop date occurs after the first day of that month. `(ITEM_START<= CalendarMonthStart and ITEM_STOP>= CalendarMonthStart)`
2. The Item Activity START date occurs after the first day of that particular month and that item's activity STOP date occurs before the last day of that particular month (activity is within the single month).`(ITEM_START>= CalendarMonthStart and ITEM_STOP>= CalendarMonthEnd)`
3. The Item Activity START date occurs before the last day of that particular month and STOPs after the last day of that particular month.`(ITEM_START<= CalendarMonthEnd and ITEM_STOP>= CalendarMonthEnd)`

An example of my proc sql query:

```
proc sql;
create table  earned_activity as

select
      a.ITEM_START,
      a.ITEM_STOP,
      b.MonthName,
      b.CalendarMonthStart,
      b.CalendarMonthEnd
/* Need to do something here */
from item_activity as a
left join calendar_table as b on 
          (ITEM_START<= CalendarMonthStart and ITEM_STOP>= CalendarMonthStart) or
          (ITEM_START>= CalendarMonthStart and ITEM_STOP>= CalendarMonthEnd) or
          (ITEM_START<= CalendarMonthEnd and ITEM_STOP>= CalendarMonthEnd)

;
quit;
```

After these three cases are joined to my data I have some example data like below:

| ITEM_START | ITEM_STOP | MonthName | CalendarMonthStart | CalendarMonthEnd | num_days_active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-06 | 2021-03-06 | Jan | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-31 | 25 |
| 2021-01-06 | 2021-03-06 | Feb | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-28 | 28 |
| 2021-01-06 | 2021-03-06 | Mar | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-31 | 6 |

As you can see, with the cartesian product I have an item with activity in three different calendar months. I would like to find a way to get the # of days that item existed in each of these months. My first idea would be to perform a cartesian product on each individual days of the month and somehow tally up if that day was active but I believe that might get massive and cumbersome quite quickly. Is there a good approach to performing this type of operation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a max of the start and min of the end, I think.

```sql
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(day,
        CASE WHEN CalendarMonthStart > a.ITEM_START THEN CalendarMonthStart ELSE a.ITEM_START END,
        CASE WHEN CalendarMonthEnd   < a.ITEM_STOP  THEN CalendarMonthEnd   ELSE a.ITEM_START END)
```

Furthermore, your `WHERE` can be much simpler:

```sql
inner join calendar_table as b on 
          (ITEM_START <= CalendarMonthEnd and ITEM_STOP => CalendarMonthStart)
```

Comment: Excellent! I will test this and see what happens. Much better ```where``` condition suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: I think this works rather well. In your second ```case when``` I think the else clause should be ```a.ITEM_STOP_DT```. Also in the ```where``` clause for the join they should include equivalent cases in the conditionals since an item could stop/start on the monthstart/monthend and we'd still want to count that single day as being an activity date.

Comment: If that is the case then you need `>=` `<=`. If you read the conditions carefully you will see that we are comparing one interval's *start* with the other's *end*, and v.v.

Comment: With your logic as written, in the case that an item's start is after (or equal) to the ```CalendarMonthStart``` and the item's stop is before the ```CalendarMonthEnd``` (basically it only has activity inside of the month), your logic will cause datediff to take the difference of days between the ITEM_STRT and the ITEM_STRT resulting in 0 days, but in fact it should be finding the  number of days it existed from ITEM_STRT to ITEM_END?